# Symfony exclude 400 errors from log

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I noticed that when I throw a `BadRequestHttpException` it is logged with Monolog.

How can I exclude specific exceptions and HTTP errors from my log? My configuration is the following:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/
        nested:
            type: rotating_file
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
            level: debug
            max_files: 30
```

Since this is an API website I have a lot of "good" 400 errors which should not be logged.

Note: I don't want to raise the level to **critical**.

Comment: Humm 400 is not good!

Comment: Relevant Github issue: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

For now the only solution I found is to manually return a view instead of throwing a `BadRequestHttpException`:

```
$response = new ApiResponse("error", 'There is already a pending request.');
return $this->view($response, 400);
```